# Find subnet of a lambda running in a vpc

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, amazon-ecs, aws-fargate

I have a lambda that needs to call ecs.run_task to start an ECS/Fargate task. I'm running in a VPC, so in order to call run_task I have to specify a subnet. Rather than figuring out what subnet to run in, is there a way to get that information from lambda itself?

As in within the lambda I could do, "Get my current subnet, and then use that in my call to ecs.run_task".

*Is* there a way to get my subnet in a lambda?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The API `GetFunctionConfiguration` is called with the Lambda Function ARN and will provide the VPC config, part of which is the Subnet Id:

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/API_GetFunctionConfiguration.html

Comment: If you have multiple possible subnets for the Lamba, this just tells you the possible ones.